# Why is it spelled "for completeness' sake" and not "for completeness's sake"?

Tags: orthography, possessives, apostrophe

Why is it spelled "for completeness' sake" and not "for completeness's sake"

Isn't the apostrophe at the end only for plural?

Comment: https://www.latimes.com/socal/burbank-leader/tn-blr-me-aword-20160715-story.html

Comment: Because at some point some people start worrying about snakes.

Comment: Was this closed for the wrong reason? The linked thread says: Use an apostrophe alone if the genitive comes "on top of" a plural form ending in s; and use an apostrophe plus s if the genitive is on something singular, like "the boss's car". But the asker of this thread already knew that and posted it in their question! Then the main answer of the linked entry has some exceptions for proper names, but "completeness" does not seem to be a proper name to me? So the question remains: Which one of **for completeness' sake** and **for completeness's sake** is correct, and why? Maybe reopen question?